# Google URL Shortener API - Getting started

Tags: google-url-shortener

I'm trying to run the sample from Google's API sample [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/url-shortener) in Script.google.com.

**Sample Code:**

```
function getClicks(shortUrl) {
  var url = UrlShortener.Url.get(shortUrl, {
    projection: 'ANALYTICS_CLICKS'
  });
  Logger.log('The URL received %s clicks this week.', url.analytics.week.shortUrlClicks);
}
```

**Error:**

```
Required parameter: shortUrl (line 2, file "Code")
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Sure shortUrl contains a valid url?

Comment: I'm not understanding your response?